# Spring JPA Hibernate how to find array column contains certain elements Named Query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, named-query

Suppose I have an entity

```
@Entity
public class Course{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String courseName;

    //getter and setters
}
```

now I want to find a `Course` by its `name`, hence in its repository, I put a named query,

```
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM course c where c.name = :name", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Course> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

Now lets say `Course` entity gets a `String[]` column which will contain the name of days the course class supposed to be held. So the entity becomes

```
@Entity
public class Course{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String courseName;

    //will contain {"Tue", "Wed", "Thr"} etc ... the class days
    private String [] classDays; 

    //getter and setters
}
```

**Now I want to find the Courses that are held in Thr.** How do I write a named query for that ? I have something like this in mind

```
SELECT * FROM course c where :day in c.class_days
```

but will that work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because classDays is not mapped to work in that way(it will be passed to the database like a bytea(postgresql) or blob(oracle) not a list of string). You can use @ElementCollection to be able to execute this query `SELECT * FROM course c where :day in c.class_days`

```
@Entity
public class Course{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String courseName;

    //will contain {"Tue", "Wed", "Thr"} etc ... the class days
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name="class_days_table",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID")
  )
  @Column(name="class_days")
    private List<String> classDays; 

    //getter and setters
}
```

Comment: excellent. anyone looking for information: the exact jpql query was @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Course as t where :day MEMBER OF c.classDays")